# Angular 4 Lazy Loading with parameters

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Hello I am attempting to lazy load a "detail module" while also sending parameters via the URL.

Here is my lazy loaded route:

```
{
    path: 'venue/:name/:id',
    loadChildren: () => System.import('../containers/activity-detail/activity-detail.module').then((file: any) => {
        return file.default;
    })
},
```

I would like to route to this 'activity-detail.module' and then load details using the ":name", and "id:" parameters.

The module which loads has its own routes file.

```
export const VenueDetailRoutes: Route[] = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'venue/:name/:id',  
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'venue/:name/:id', 
        component: VenueDetailComponent,
        data: {
            shouldDetach: true, // Route will be resused. See CustomResuseStrategy.
            title: null
        }
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '/'
    }

];
```

It seems without the first default object nothing works. I get the error:

```
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'venue/:name/:id', 
    pathMatch: 'full'
},

TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of null
```

With the default object in place I get the error:

```
Error: Cannot redirect to 'venue/:name/:id'. Cannot find ':name'.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think that this works:

```js
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'venue/:name/:id',  
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
```

It can't match an "empty" path to a path with parameters.

The syntax for your lazy loaded route is quite a bit more complex than mine. Mine looks like this:

```js
{
    path: 'movies',
    loadChildren: './movies/movie.module#MovieModule'
},
```

Notice that "parent" route ('movies' in this example) is defined here on the lazy loaded route, and NOT repeated in the loaded modules routes.

For example:

```js
RouterModule.forChild([
  { path: '', component: MovieListComponent },
  { path: 'search', component: MovieSearchComponent },
  { path: ':id', component: MovieDetailComponent }
])
```

I would think in your case that the loaded module's routes should look something like this:

```js
export const VenueDetailRoutes: Route[] = [
    {  
       path: ':name/:id', 
       component: VenueDetailComponent,
        data: {
            shouldDetach: true, // Route will be resused. See CustomResuseStrategy.
            title: null
        }
    }    
];
```

(Though you may want to consider leaving off the custom reuse strategy until you have the basic routes working.)

Comment: you def deserve a hug and cuddle. Thank you very much.

Comment: ouch, and on same month as Harvey Weinstein outing.

Comment: Great! It worked for my project this example for RouterModule.forChild was very helpful. A parameter in the lazy loading path for the module was my error and it affected the ngx-translator with localize-router so the url in the change of language gets errors.

Comment: Thanks, mate, you saved my day. I was using `{ path: '/:id'}` but from your answer, I got to knew that it has to be  `{ path: 'id' }` without the backslash.