# Lazy load module with route params and named router outlet

Tags: angular

I have a route / component that requires a route parameter and has a named outlet. I want to lazy load a module and activate this route. Here are my routes:

Profile Module (sub module) Routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: ':id', component: ProfileComponent
  children: [
   { path: 'list/:id', component: ListComponent, outlet: 'sidebar' },
   { path: 'risk/:id', component: RiskComponent, outlet: 'sidebar' }
  ], 
];
```

Parent Module Routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'projects/profile',
    loadChildren: './profile/profile.module#ProfileModule' }
 ]
```

Loading the route results in the error:

*Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'projects/profile/-3'*

When I use an empty string for the path in the sub module, there is no error and the module loads but the component doesn't load. I found [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46921614/6569899) with lazy loading route params and [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47487220/6569899) with lazy loading named router outlets, but neither worked.

My question is:
How do I lazy load a route with a route parameter and named router outlet?

--Edit--

Here is a [demo app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-communicating-between-components-x7phcm) that shows my problem. I created 3 main routes: one that lazy loads a submodule without named outlets, one the that lazy loads with a named outlet, and one that doesn't use lazy loading. In the UI, the link to the route that has a named outlet produces the error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trial and error I found an answer. I created this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-communicating-between-components-5wgu5q) that implements it. As a note I need multiple router-outlets with route params (the demo only contains a component that has one router outlet, but my actual app has two. Hence I need it to be named)

**Parent Module**

As Thomas Cayne mentions, the link to lazy loading the module is the following (Note the lack of :id route parameter. This is because this route is used for lazy loading only):

```
{ path: 'profile', loadChildren: () => import('./profile/profile.module').then(m => m.ProfileModule) },
```

**Sub Module**

The routing in the submodule is the following: (The top level route has the :id route param as its component needs to use the :id. The child outlet in my case requires an :id as well. The outlet uses the param to load its data.)

```
 const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
   path: 'test/:id', component: ProfileComponent,
   children: [
    { path: 'bar/:id', component: SidebarComponent, outlet:'sidebar' }
   ] 
  },
 ];
```

**Parent Template**

Finally the routerLink that correctly routes to the component with a named router outlet and route params through a lazy loaded module is as follows:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/', 'profile', 'test', 3, { outlets: { sidebar: ['bar', 3 ] } }]">Working Router outlet and route params</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have `component: ProfileComponent` twice. Is that what you want? That might be causing the routing issue.

Also, for lazy loading your module which contains it's children, in your parent route, you can also do:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'projects/profile',
    loadChildren: () => import('./profile/profile.module').then(m => m.ProfileModule')
  }
 ]
```

If you had a demo app diagnosing it would be helpful. A StackBlitz example could help more.

**UPDATE:**

In you app.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'profile',
    loadChildren: () => import('./profile/profile.module').then(m => m.ProfileModule')
  }
 ]
```

In your profile.routing.ts:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', 
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: ProfileComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'sidebar', component: SidebarComponent,
    children: [
    {
     path: ':id',
    component: AdminUserDetailsComponent,
    }
    ]
  },
];
```

I don't think you need the `name="sidebar" in``. Make it`` because you're already inside a module. PathMatch: 'full':

> pathMatch = 'full' results in a route hit when the remaining,
>   unmatched segments of the URL match is the prefix path

https://angular.io/guide/router#set-up-redirects

Finally, you links should navigate to the full path:

```
  <a [routerLink]="['/profile/sidebar']">Outlet defined and specified doesn't work (ProfileModule)</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['/profile']">With outlet defined but not specified (ProfileModule: '/profile/3')</a>
```

I never use inline params route because they are difficult to read, navigate, figure out and debug.

Comment: Here is a [demo app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-communicating-between-components-x7phcm) I created StackBlitz. I created 3 main routes: one that lazy loads a submodule without named outlets, one the that lazy loads with a named outlet, and one that doesn't use lazyloading. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the demo. It was very helpful. Please see my update above

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I do, however need the named router outlet as my actual application has two outlets on the ProfileComponent page. I only had one for brevity purposes. Those outlets need route parameters as well. After some testing I found something that works. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be different from classic lazy loading, what may be causing the problem is path: `':id'` in profile routing, try changing it to empty `path: ''`, you may also move the `:id` up to the parent route path: `'projects/profile/:id'`

Comment: I tried moving the :id up to the parent and it doesn't work. However, it does work if I remove the :id entirely, but my page doesn't load. (I got the idea to add the id to the sub module route from the first link I provided above)

Comment: After trying a number of permutations, I did get this to partially work. After moving the :id to the parent I found that the following route worked: http://localhost:4200/projects/profile/18. However, the named router outlets did not work. The navigating to the route: http://localhost:4200/projects/profile/18/(sidebar:list/18)  gives the error mentioned above.

Comment: I added an example project above. Any feed back would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this info
https://newbedev.com/angular-4-lazy-loading-with-named-router-outlet-not-working
A workaround is to avoid blank paths in lazy loaded modules when using named outlets.  Angular has a bug for this, but it was closed since no one would provide an example.  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16406

Try this in your stackblitz project:

```
  path: 'profileoutlet', component: ProfileComponent,
   children: [
    { path: 'bar/:id', component: SidebarComponent, outlet:'sidebar' }
  ]
```

in profile.routing.ts and

```
  <a [routerLink]="['/', 'profile', 3, 'profileoutlet', { outlets: { sidebar: ['bar', 3 ] } }]">Outlet defined and specified doesn't work (ProfileModule)</a>
```

for the link in app.component.ts