# Modifying a Type to have a new property inside nested object (Routes)

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to add that whenRoute optional parameter to data inside the Route type, how do I do it without modifying angular types file directly ?

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'pages',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pages.module').then(m => m.PagesModule),
    data: { whenRoute: '/test'}
  }
]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46921179/angular-4-lazy-loading-with-parameters   see this link

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to modify any types. the data property is of type Data which has the following declaration:

```
export declare type Data = {
    [name: string]: any;
};
```

In other words you can put any named property in your data object, and those properties can have any values.